# SQL Where Clause Returning Multiple Results

Tags: sql, firebird, where-clause, firebird2.1

I have a SQL Statement with multiple conditions in the WHERE clause, however once one condition is met, the query stops. What I need is for the query to return ALL rows pertaining to one of the conditions.

For example:

```
select * from EMPLOYEE_LEAVE
where
   ENUMBER = :num
   or
   EFNAME = 'Sebastien'
   or 
   ESNAME = :sname
```

In this case, the query must search for all records where EFNAME is Sebastien. I have two records in my database that match this condition however the query only returns the first result. How would I go about showing ALL records that match this condition?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Is the search case sensitive?

Comment: Sql will return the set with all matching rows so something else must be wrong. Which dbms/server are you using and how do you evaluate the result?

Comment: Are you perhaps expecting to get the same row back multiple times if the row matches more than one condition? If so `UNION ALL` might be what you require (although I can't see why this would be desirable)

Comment: @Oded and @faester - I am using Firebird 2.1 with Database Workbench 4 Lite for Firebird. Could the problem be with Database Workbench since all I am doing is writing the statement and executing it? @John-Pickup No, two different rows. I have Sebastien Smith and Sebastien Russell in my database, when using the above query to search for Sebastien I'm expecting two rows to be returned but only Sebastien Russell is returned.

Comment: Does SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_LEAVE where EFNAME='Sebastien' return both rows?

Comment: What do you get with WHERE EFNAME LIKE 'Sebast%'   ? How about with WHERE TRIM(EFNAME) = 'Sebastien' ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL will return all rows matching your conditions. if you only get the first row, then this is not a SQL issue, but one of your front-end programming. Give examples of your code, and we can answer what you make wrong.

Comment: Hi @TomTom - Thanks for your reply. The SQL snippet in my question is the statement I am using inside Database Workbench 4 Lite for Firebird, I have not implemented any front-end development as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a special character in Sebastien Smith's name, that's not immediately visible in the tool you are using. (like Sébastien for example)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. Database Workbench doesn't update the SQL Editor window when changes are made to the database. I had to close the SQL editor and reopen it for the editor to see the changes, I noticed this from @N-West and @Tim 's comments (both queries returned only one row, by the way).